# How to escape filename for the quickfix list?

Tags: quickfix

Let's say you have a filename containing a tab.

```
$ echo stuff > foo$'\t'bar
```

Inside Vim you want to add that file to the quickfix list.

By way of context, if you use a single-quoted string, a.k.a string literal, like this:

```
:call setqflist([{'filename': 'foo\tbar', 'lnum': 1, 'text': 'stuff'}])
```

– then when you try to open the sole entry in the quickfix list, Vim opens a new file instead.

If you use double-quotation marks (`"foo\tbar"`) it all works.

Now here's my problem: I obtain the filename from `git-diff` which quotes the filename in its output like this:

```
diff --git "foo\tbar" "foo\tbar"
```

Inside my code I extract the name from between the quotes, giving me `foo\tbar` in a variable.  Then I use this variable for the filename in `setqflist()`.  However it's effectively a string literal rather than a double-quoted string and doesn't work.

I have tried escaping the tab character (`foo\\tbar`) but that doesn't work either.

How can I get Vim to recognise that the filename contains a tab?

Comment: My code is [here](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/blob/ded11946c04aeab5526f869174044019ae9e3c32/autoload/gitgutter.vim#L212-L231) if anyone wants to see it.